# Visual studio C++ にClangを導入したい

Tags: visual-studio, clang

最近VSを使い始めた者です

そこで[この記事](https://qiita.com/kazatsuyu/items/b85e97e38a25bc302054)をみて、Clangをこの方法で使ってみたいなと思い以下のコードで試してみたんですが、

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n" << endl;
}
```

デバッグして実行しようとしたら、

> could not create the new file tracking log file C:(プロジェクトのディレクトリ)\Debug\～～.tlog\clang.5504.5276.read.1.tlog. The filename, directoryname, or volumelabel syntax is incorrect.

みたいなエラーが3つ出てきて、動きませんでした。
・これは、例の方法でコンパイラーを変えたことが原因でしょうか？
・どうすれば解決できるのでしょうか

VSは英語版を使っています（住んでいる場所が英語圏なので何となく）
全然使ったことがないので、よくわからないため、変な質問かもしれませんがお願いします！

Comment: Visual StudioでClangを使用される理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: https://qiita.com/kazatsuyu/items/b85e97e38a25bc302054
これを見て、ClangのほうがMicrosoft製コンパイラーよりも優れているように感じたからです

Comment: 挙げられたコード例であればVC++でもコンパイルできます。筆者がVC++の使い方を知らないまま貶しているだけです。VC++でもClangでもそれぞれを使うのは簡単だと思いますが、無理に組み合わせるのは困難ですのでおすすめしません。

Comment: そうですね。たしかにそのとおりだと思います。